# Dissecting a figure into three congruent parts in three different ways

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

Figure 1 is divided in 2 equal parts of same size and shape in 3 different ways

[image]

Figure 2 is divided in 3 equal parts of same size and shape in 2 different ways

[image]

Is it possible to find a figure that can be divided in 3 equal parts of same size and shape in precisely 3 different ways using polyominoes, polyamonds or polyhexes?

Comment: Do all three shapes need to be *distinct*? Or is it okay if there are, say, two different dissections into P-pentominoes?

Comment: Do you mean *exactly* 3 different ways? As it is possible to divide an equilateral triangle into 3 equal shapes in far more than 3 different ways...

Comment: @Stiv yes I mean in  exactly 3 different ways

Comment: @Deusovi no, the three shapes need to be distinct

Comment: This information might be useful in your question.

Comment: Do you intend the shapes to be polyominoes, as in the examples?

Comment: @DanielMathias No, not necessarily.

Comment: Here, "Exactly 3 ways" is going to be very Difficult to Prove. In your Examples, we can not Prove that there are no other ways to Dissect. We can change the Puzzle to (1) "At least 3 ways, with Each Solution having 3 Equal Parts and these Parts are Unique to that Solution" or  (2) "At least 3 ways, with Each Solution having 3 Equal Parts and these Parts are not necessarily Unique to that Solution" ....

Comment: If the three dissections did not need to use different shapes then example #2 could already be done in three ways: In the L-pentomino dissection the L-pair forming a rectangle can be flipped.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis , In my earlier comment, I mentioned that "In [OP] Examples, we can not Prove that there are no other ways to Dissect" and here you are Proving that there are indeed other ways to Dissect !!!!

Comment: @Prem if we go out of polyamonds or polyominoes I accept any solution that has 3 or more different solutions but not infinity

Comment: If I have 2 placements that are similar but only mirrored (e.g. one with L-tetromino and another one with J-tetromino), do they count as one or two ways?

Comment: @athin if are same pieces will count as one way, the 3 solutions should be with 3 sets of different pieces

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with polyamonds of a figure that can be divided in 3 equal parts of same size and shape in precisely 3 different ways:

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect; the given shape can be divided in 3 equals parts of same size and shape in more than 3 different ways. For example, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkDJp.png) is another way.

Comment: Excellent @Avi so the puzzle is still open for polyamonds too!

Comment: So this answer makes an incorrect claim? I suggest you should either [edit] it or delete it then.

Comment: Your Dissection in Green & the Dissection given by @Avi both have Mirror Image Dissections, giving a total of 6 Ways .... [[ I am not DownVoting your Question & your Answer, but I can see why some users may have wanted to DownVote .... Basically, there is a lack of focus, which you should take as constructive feedback ]] .... Your Puzzle is not originally about Polyamonds, but after lots of refinement, your answer is restricting to Polyamonds ; While restricting to Polyamonds or Polyominoes, naturally there can not be infinite solutions. It will be good to add all criteria in the Question.

Comment: Thanks @Prem I ask now only using polyominoes, polyamonds or polyhexes

Answer (score 1):

Here is a heptiamond tiling with exactly three sets of three. Method of solution: Start with an arbitrary shape with 60 degree rotational symmetry, I used a triangle of side 6 which fits 3 12-iamonds. Fed it through my solver which says 20 12-iamonds tile it. Move on to smaller and smaller shapes and smaller sets (eg octiamonds into a side-2 hexagon has 5 tilings) until I settled on heptiamonds into a 2-hex which has 24 triangles, needing three removed. This was the first location I tried for those three. Oh and I tried polyominoes too, finding very few results up to 12-ominoes in a multitude of shapes.

> [image]

Here's a triple for three tetrahexes...

> [image]

Comment: There are more than three ways to divide up that figure into three congruent pieces. I don't have the ability at the moment to draw it, but another way is the same as your first way except that the diagonal line joining the top of the right triangle to the top-right corner of the figure instead joins the top of the right triangle to the top-left corner of the figure (and the others are adjusted to match). (Note that the question didn't demand division along omino lines.)

Comment: Actually you can change the angle of that line by an arbitrary amount. I suspect that any shape based on 60 degree rotational symmetry will have this issue. And figures not based on such symmetry are much harder to find... back to the drawing board.

Comment: @theonetruepath your solution is OK for the part of polyamonds. It will be great if there is a solution with polyominoes, or someone can prove that it is impossible.

Comment: @theonetruepath can you find a solution for polyhexes?

Comment: @RodolfoKurchan Probably... my first attempt was a hexagon with area 19 cells, remove centre, then four different hexahexes tile it. You have the same sort of lattitude as polyiamonds and similar ways to deform each tiling into an infinity of shapes.

Comment: Added the polyhex solution. The next one I tried after the four way hexahex.

Comment: @theonetruepath excelent your solution with tetrahexes!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm still very unsure about the puzzle. But if I understand the rules correctly, does this answer your question in polyamonds?

> [image]

Comment: The first two dissections use the same shapes. Mirror images do not count as different.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis My reading comprehension might be bad, but I thought it's pointed several times from comments that mirror images are different? (I asked about L and J-tetrominoes cases as well although now I realized OP's answer is very vague for me...)

Comment: $\raise -.1ex@$athin, @Jaap Scherphuis and you are truly inspired dissecters.  As for one of my dissection puzzles, you snuck up on the solution.  My sniffer senses the same here.  ^vote in imagination of what all  solutions you've already considered and what you might yet.

Comment: @athin in figure 1 and 2 you repeate pieces, is considered same solution

Comment: @RodolfoKurchan May I know what exactly does "repeating pieces" mean? Correct me if I'm wrong: so mirroring counts as one?

Comment: @athin Take a closer look at the two examples. They both include mirrored pieces. However it is possible to answer both polyiamond and polyhex questions with unmirrored pieces, see my answer.